# log in session in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, session

how can i update the user data by determining the user logged in session? right now im just inserting one user id to test if my code works however i am not sure how to use session instead.

my controller

```
 public function index(){
    // check whether user login
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('home');
        }
        else{
      $this->login();
        }
  }
function update_user() {


   $this->form_validation->set_rules('sirname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {


            $data = array(
                'surname' => $this->input->post('sirname'),
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            );

            $this->Account_model->update_user(31,$data); //change the 31 id to session??


        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Updated!</div>');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
      // redirect('home');
      }

      else 
      {
        $data['titile'] = 'Edit User';
        $data['display'] = 'displayname';
        $data['single_user'] = $this->Account_model->show_user(31);//change the 31 id to session??
        $this->load->view('template/header.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('update_view', $data);

      }
}
```

my model

```
function show_user($data){
        $this->db->where('pkid', $data);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $query_result = $query->result();

        return $query_result;
    }



function show($data){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('pkid', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;
}

// Update Query For Selected Student
function update_user($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('pkid', $id);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
}
```

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/session-handling-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You will have to need to have the session library loaded. You also need to have set the user's id (or uesername) set to a session variable. Make sure you use that session variable in your update query.

```
$userID = $this->session->userdata('id'); // Needes to be previously set after the successful login attempt
$this->Account_model->update_user($userID, $data);
```

BTW, you need to load the form_validation library before using it's functions.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules(...);
```